# <ul> inside <ol> in editor

Tags: html, editor

I want to add

```
<ol>
   <li>First list</li>
   <li>Second List 
      <ul>
          <li>Sub Second List</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Third List </li>
</ol>
```

This is not possible with editor without manual job. How can we achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is entirely possible, as I just tested it in WordPress.

1. Create your unordered list
2. Add four items: "First list," "Second list," "Sub Second List," "Third List"
3. Place the cursor on "Sub Second List" and click Indent (you will need to expand the kitchen sink to access the indent button
4. With the cursor still on "Sub Second List," click Unordered List

Following the steps above will produce the following markup:

```
<ol>
    <li>First List</li>
    <li>Second List
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Second List</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Third List</li>
</ol>
```